# 無限ループで先に進みません

Tags: c++

これ以降どうすればいいのか分かりません
「国語、英語、数学のデータを別ファイルから読み取り、その合計点から1位、2位、3位を表示する」というプログラムを作りたいのですが
c++ で書いています。コンパイルまではエラーが出ないのですが実行しようとしても進みません。どこかで何かが無限ループしてるような気がしますが自分には分かりませんどなたか教えてください。

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{FILE*f;
    float kokugo[10],suugaku[10],eigo[10],xmax,sum[10],sumdummy;
    int i,j,jmin,n;
    f=fopen("ファイル名","r");

    if(f==NULL){
        printf("ファイル名を開けません"\n");
        return 1; 
    }

    for(i=0;i<30;i+3)
        fscanf(f,"%g",kokugo[i]);

    for(i=0;i<30;i+3)
        fscanf(f,"%g",suugaku[i]);

    for(i=0;i<30;i+3)
        fscanf(f,"%g",eigo[i]);

    fclose(f);

    if(n==0){
        printf("ファイル名にはデータがありません);
        return1;
    }

    for(j=0;j<=10;j++){
        sum[j]=kokugo[i]+suugaku[i]+eigo[i];
    }

    for(j=0;j<10;j=j+1){
        if (sum[j]<sum[jmin])jmin=j;
    }

    if(j!=jmin){
        sumdummy=sum[j];
        sum[j]=sum[jmin];
        sum[jmin]=sumdummy;
    }

    for(j=0;j<=3;j++){
        printf ("%g",sum[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

点数のデータ
1人目の国語
1人目の数学
1人目の英語
↓
↓
10人目の国語
10人目の数学
10人目の英語

Comment: `for(i=0;i<30;i+3)` となっていますが、`kokugo[10],suugaku[10], ...` としている事から、これは `for(i=0;i<10;i++)` とすべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: と思ったのですが、どうやらデータの並び方が、"国語の点数","数学の点数", "英語の点数" となっていて、それが10人分続いているのでしょうか？

Comment: 国語、数学、英語の順で縦に30行で書いたものを読み込んでいます。なので国語はi=0から始め、+3させて配列に入れています。

Comment: その場合、例えば `kokugo[12]` に値を入れる事になってしまいますのでエラーになってしまいます(配列の `index out of range error`)。

Comment: なるほど。では配列の0番目にデータ中の1番目、配列の1番目にデータ中の4番目を入れるにはどうすればいいですか？変数を変えればいいですか？

Comment: 例えば `float exam_result[30];`  としてデータファイルの内容を全て読み込んで、それぞれの合計点を計算する際に `for(j=0;j<10;j++){ sum[j]=exam_result[3*j]+exam_result[3*j+1]+exam_result[3*j+2];}` などとしてみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: 別ファイルに書いたデータを編集して質問文に載せました。ご提案いただいた式だと別ファイルのデータを編集する必要はありますか？

Comment: データファイルにヘッダ（データの属性やコメントが書かれている行）が無ければ問題ありません(編集の必要はありません)。

Comment: もしよろしければ追加でお答えいただきたいのですが、1位、2位、3位の表示方法についてアドバイスいただけますか？

Comment: @metropolis ＠佐藤大輝 コメントで回答をやりとりするよりも、回答を投稿するか、チャットルームを立ててはいかがでしょうか？また、表示方法まで行くと質問の本題からそれすぎているかと思いますので、新しく質問を立てた方がいいかと思います。

Comment: そうですね。申し訳ありません。

Comment: @metropolis 過去にも何度かお伝えしていますが、コメント欄で回答を行わないで下さい。コメント欄で完結したやり取りは、どれだけ役立つ情報だとしてもシステム的には「回答なし」と同じ状態で好ましくありません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for文で `for(i=0;i<30;i+3)` となっていますが、この `i` の値が更新されていないのが原因です。`for(i=0;i<30;i=i+3)`に修正してみましょう。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。早速直してみましたが、動作を停止しましたと出てきました…何がいけなのでしょうか

Comment: 詳細なエラー文を合わせて新しく別の質問を作成してください。

Comment: 配列外アクセスでしょうね。4回目のループで`[12]`を使っちゃいます。